# EPPlus Excel file Opening error

Tags: excel, epplus

I am using EPPlus open source tool for open excel files on server. 
When I try to open it using EPPlus some time I am getting error. Then I download it to local machine & when I open it using MS Excel I got error like excel found unreadable content Do you want to recover workbook? 
I repair it using MS Excel again upload it and then it start working correctly.

What is actual problem?
Can I reapair it using EPPlus itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unreadable content in Excel file generated with EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906666/unreadable-content-in-excel-file-generated-with-epplus)

Comment: How can I avoid that Unreadable content generated with EPPlus is there any way do to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with new version of EPPlus

EPPlus 4.0 fixed mostly bugs

Save() and Dispose() created instance of excelPackage for better performance