# Unreadable excel content Epplus

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus-4

I am making a Post request and receiving the response from an end point, through which i receive the excel content.

I have used this end point before and tried binding a email worker, which works fine. (Conforming end point response is clear).

Now with a different requirement, i need to make the post call to this end point and download the excel file.xlsx file hence generated is corrupted and i excel tries to recover it once the file is downloaded.

Have gone thorugh different threads and tried almost everything.

Nothing seems to work.

try 1:

```
Response.Clear();
 stream.Flush();
 stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName.Replace("\"", String.Empty));
```

And while debugging i have made sure to close the response. (Response.End()).
Have even added the explicit headers

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=\"" fileName".xlsx\"");

 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
```

Try 2

have explicity written the memoryStream to the response.
Response.BinaryWrite(tgtBytes);

Have ensured Response.Clear before writing to response and making  sure of memoryStream.dispose and Response.End. 
Have even used. Response.ClearHeaders().

Try - 3.

Instead of MemoryStream, tried with filestream, saving in a file and downloading from the File written. Problem still Persists.

I am getting a binaryStream as response and no encoding in done as it isn't hex value.

Either the stream is corrupted ( which is likely not the case, as i use the end point for different requirements) or the response is corrupted.

how should i check what is the exact cause ??
Please Let me know what else can  i try.

Comment: Is the xlsx you are generating exactly the same as what you successfully generated previously with your mail worker?  Or is it a different file/format generated by epplus?  What about calling `Response.End()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906666/unreadable-content-in-excel-file-generated-with-epplus?rq=1